# Why doesn't the javaw.exe start when i open Eclipse or NEtbeans?

Tags: java, jvm

When i open Eclipse or Netbeans the Java virtual machine process javaw i can't see the javaw process in the processes list. Shouldn't i be able to?

Comment: Am not really sure why javaw should come, but a 'java' process does get created when you launch Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably wrapped by some other process, which creates the JVM programmatically. You can do this for your own application with [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Netbeans, but Eclipse is started by eclipse.exe, which I can find easily in my Windows XP processes list in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans and eclipse are started by Windows Launcher applications that are written possibly in C/C++ - they are not direct Java calls.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Eclipse doesn't run in a virtual machine and doesn't start the virtual machine until you run your code.</strike> I *think* that when you run multiple instances of your code it runs them in separate virtual machines, so you should only see a java or javaw process when your code is running.

Try running code containing `while(true){}` and see if you can see the process then.

Comment: Eclipse is written in Java, and *does* run in a VM. Just not the one created by javaw, but by eclipse.exe.

Comment: Oh, okay! Does it still start new VMs for every code instance?

Comment: If you start/debug your code it will start a separate VM for that, yes.